# Error : when I'm trying to submit my first app (iTunes store operation failed)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to submit my first iphone app to the app store but when click on validate or submit to App store I get this Error :
Itunes store operation failed.
the network connection was lost.

can anyone help me please?

Comment: This is not really programming related. And there's not a lot of information to go on. Either your network connection dropped or there's a problem on Apple's end.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with my connection !
and I won't count on the apple's end idea -because it may not be the problem either \1 -

Answer (score 0):

You should check your certificates and provisioning profiles in member center.

I recommend you to this :

1- Delete all your dist certificates and provisioning files in developer.apple.com

2- Create again new dist certificates and provisioning file there. Download them and double click to install

3- XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts in the window, bottom right click view details

4- Check that your new dist files there

5- Archive and send again

Comment: try to check your settings in Build Settings -> Code Signing screen i added the screen shot. Your certificates should be selected here         https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53894534/jjk.jpg

Comment: I have the same settings  !
now I get to this screen then I get the same error :
http://s3.postimg.org/ed0aeb25v/Screen_Shot_2015_05_30_at_8_47_30_PM.png

Comment: http://s7.postimg.org/mm80a2lff/Screen_Shot_2015_05_30_at_9_09_18_PM.png
did you mean this ?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to upload my app !
the problem was with the connection !
I had to use a vpn service to upload the app !